# How can I find and replace color in Draw.io?

Tags: app.diagrams.net

I want to replace all the red in these shapes with blue. Is there a fast way to do that? [image: Red Cards]

Maybe replace "FF0000" with "0000FF" but I'm not sure how to do that on Draw.io

Comment: those are objects, right?

Comment: @MARKMYANSWER Yes, those are shapes from the general tab (not pictures)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- select them holding **<kbd>CTRL</kbd>** key
- click on color under **Fill** section
- change color and **Apply**

[image]

Comment: A little faster, but seems like the only possible solution right now until draw.io puts a new feature, thanks!